# Trying to implement a simple one-time bubble sort in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a bubble sort. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double small;
    double big;
    double i;
    vector<double>list;
    while(cin){
        cin>>i;
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++){
        small=list[i];
        big=list[i+1];
        if(small<=big){
        }
        else{
            list[i]=big;
            list[i+1]=small;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++)
        cout<<list[i]<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my input:

```
123
4141
515
231366
21378
12990
5
6
8
9
```

but it outputs this:

```
123
515
4141
21378
12990
5
6
8
9        
9        
231366
```

The expected output should be: 5,6,8,9,123,515,4141,12990,21378,231366.(Ignore this, I was being dumb, the output is correct besides for the duplicated number). Any help? Sorry if this trivial.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: This isn't clear.  What output were you expecting?

Comment: If by 'only goes through one-time' you mean one iteration of the sort, then your output is correct (however I think you wrote `9` twice there). If you mean something else, please explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

9 is read twice since you are using `while(cin)`, it should be

```
while(cin >> i){
    list.push_back(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an extra `9` because it is the last thing you input and you are not breaking out of the loop correctly.  Therefore you end up adding it to your list twice.  Something like this is more appropriate:

```
while(cin>>i){
  list.push_back(i);
  cout << "Adding " << i << "\n";
}
```

In your previous cause you had the following:

```
while(cin){
    cin>>i; // <-- reaches the end of file
    list.push_back(i); // <-- puts something in the list even though we didn't read anything
}
```

Note that when `cin` reaches the `EOF` you will still add `i` to the list, which still has its old value as `cin` didn't read in any input besides `EOF`.  The correct I have in the first code segment fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your input loop is running one too many times giving a duplicate element at the end of the list.  If you change the while loop to be:

```
 while(cin >> i){
    list.push_back(i);
 }
```

then the last element is only added once.  You will also need to change the bounds on the output loop.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483126/whats-the-difference-between-whilecin-and-whilecin-num) about `while (cin)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a nested loop

```
for(j=0;j<list.size()-1;j++){
    for(i=0;i<list.size()-1-j;i++){
```

right now you are moving 231366, the biggest number, to the end of the list. You have to iterate on.