# Why am I getting an infinite loop (factors)?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

> The proper divisors of a positive integer, n, are all the positive integers that divide n evenly other than n itself. For example, the proper divisors of 16 are 1, 2, 4, and 8.

An abundant number is an integer greater than 0 such that the sum of its proper divisors is greater than the integer. For example, 12 is abundant because 1+2+3+4+6 = 16 which is greater than 12.

A deficient number is an integer greater than 0 such that the sum of its proper divisors is less than the integer. For example, 8 is deficient because 1+2+4 = 7 which is less than 8.

A perfect number is an integer greater than 0 such that the sum of its proper divisors is equal to the integer. For example, 6 is perfect because 1+2+3 = 6.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E5E9.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      int current;
      int possible;
      int sum=0;
      int facts=0;

      cin >> current;
```

> the current is: 17 -5 246

```
      while(cin){
        cout << current;
        for (possible=1; possible<= current; possible++)
          {
            if(current%possible==0)
              {
              sum= sum + possible;
              facts++;
             if(sum-current > current)
              cout << "is abundant and has" << facts  << "factors" << endl;
            if(sum-current < current)
              cout << "is deficient" << endl;
            if(current < 2)
              cout << "is not abundant, deficient or perfect" << endl;
            if(current == sum-current)
              cout << "is perfect" << endl;

          }
        }
      }

        return 0;
      }
```

> This is what I should be getting:
>   17 is deficient
>   -5 is not abundant, deficient or perfect.
>   246 is abundant and has 8 factors
>   instead I get an infinite loop

Comment: Time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and specifically learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code line by line and monitor variables and their values.

Comment: A hint though, and something [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (also discussed in my previous link) would help you find (as well as stepping through your code line by line): When and where to do you read input?

Comment: Do you know what's the meaning of `while(cin) { /*...*/ }`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using ***cin*** as a condition for *while* loop, as the loop will continue to execute till there's no more data to be read.

Refer [What's the difference between while(cin) and while(cin >> num)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483126/whats-the-difference-between-whilecin-and-whilecin-num)

Instead input the current number inside while loop i.e

```
while(cin >> current){
    /* Your code */
}
```

> Note:
>
> To stop reading input from user in Linux terminal, enter Ctrl+D

And I also see that your logic is not right so you might be getting wrong results, and this you must be solving on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use int current[3] instead of int current
and check receiving end of current array instead of while(cin)