# c++ variable sized arrays from Hackerrank with vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I wanted to solve a challenge named "Variable sized Arrays" on Hackerrank and I wanted to do that using vectors. The Code I wrote, doesn't work properly and I tried debugging it, but I'm getting nowhere. I'll be grateful for 
Here's the challenge:

> Consider an n-element array,a, where each index i in the array contains a reference K<sub>i</sub>to an array of  integers (where the value of  K<sub>i</sub> varies from array to array). See the Explanation section below for a diagram.
>
> Given a, you must answer q queries. Each query is in the format i j, where i denotes an index in array  and j denotes an index in the array located at a[i] . For each query, find and print the value of element j in the array  at location  on a[i]a new line.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of n (the number of variable-length arrays) and q (the number of queries). 
>   Each line  of the  subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format k a[i]0 a[i]1 … a[i]k-1 describing the k-element array located at a[i].
>   Each of the q subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of i (an index in array a) and j (an index in the array referenced by a[i]) for a query.
>
> Sample Input
>   2 2
>   3 1 5 4
>   5 1 2 8 9 3
>   0 1
>   1 3
>
> Sample Output
>   5
>   9

So here's my code for this (I'll leave it with the couts for debugging):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    int numberOfQueries = 0;
    int numberOfArrays = 0;
    cout << "Enter Nr.Of Arrays followed by Nr.Of Queries:";
    cin >> numberOfArrays >> numberOfQueries;
    cout << "Nr.Of Arrays: " << numberOfArrays << endl;
    cout << "Nr.Of Queries: " << numberOfQueries << endl;
    vector<vector<int>>multiArray;
    cout << "MultiArray size: " << multiArray.size();
    while (numberOfArrays != 0) {
        int vsize = 0;
        cout << "\nenter array starting by its size: ";
        cin >> vsize;
        cout << " Size entered  is: " << vsize << endl;
        vector<int> vec1(vsize);
        cout << "Array Size is: " << vec1.size() << endl;
        //int element = 0;
        while (cin >> vsize) {
            cout << "Element is: " << vsize << "\n";
            vec1.push_back(vsize);
        };
        multiArray.push_back(vec1);
        numberOfArrays--;
        cout << "MultiArray size: " << multiArray.size();
        cout << "Nr.Of Arrays: " << numberOfArrays << endl;
    };
    while (numberOfQueries > 0) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        cout << "\nQuery indexes:";
        cin >> i >> j;
        cout << multiArray[i][j];
        numberOfQueries--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `while (cin >> vsize)` does? Hint: it **doesn't** scan untill an enter has been pressed

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (cin >> vsize) {
        cout << "Element is: " << vsize << "\n";
        vec1.push_back(vsize);
    };
```

should be something like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vsize; ++i) {
        int elem;
        cin >> elem;
        cout << "Element is: " << elem << "\n";
        vec1.push_back(elem);
    }
```

`while (cin >> vsize)` isn't going to stop asking for input until you get end of file or an error. But you know how many inputs to expect so code that in a for loop.

Comment: but why does it behave like that? I also suspected this, but according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483126/whats-the-difference-between-whilecin-and-whilecin-num     , if cin's buffer become empty it should terminate or did I get that wrong?

Comment: @noobnomore you got that wrong, `cin >> x` will *pause* if it's buffer is empty, but it won't return until either it's read x or it knows it can't (because of end of file, i/o error or format error)

Comment: but the answer says "terminate" and I also read in Andrew Koening "Accelerated C++" that he used: while(cin >> x){ ++count; sum += x;} in 3.1 and it worked. That's why I'm having hard time with the answer. Sorry for bothering you, but could you maybe elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @noobnomore If you do `while(cin >> x)` then  cin will read the entire file because cin will only return false when it reaches the end of the file.  But you want to read a specified number of items (however many are on the rest of the line) so reading the whole file isn't right.

Comment: @noobnomore The other way to do this if you don't want to read the count at the start of the line is to use std::getline to read one line at a time and then stick that in a std::stringstream and read the individual items from there.  But that is way more work than just using the count at the start of the line.

Comment: @noobnomore  The answer in the link you gave says "as soon as cin is closed, the loop terminates"  When it says "closed" it means that cin ran out of data (either because of the end of the file or some other error)

Comment: @noobnomore They're referring to forcing an EOF using something like CTRL + Z. If you don't do that, the program will just wait for you to enter more stuff.

Comment: @noobnomore The code `while(cin >> x){ ++count; sum += x;}` is a perfectly good way of reading **all** the numbers available and summing them. But you want to read a **fixed** number of items so a while loop is not approriate.

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanations :), it's clear now. And sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0):

My answer.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    int n,q;
    cin >> n >> q ;

    vector<int> a[n];

    int k;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> k; 
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            int val_a_i_j;
            cin >> val_a_i_j;
            a[i].push_back(val_a_i_j);
        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        int a_i, j;
        cin >> a_i >> j;
        cout << a[a_i][j] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a , b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    vector<int> arr[a];
    for(int i= 0 ; i < a ; i++)
    {
       int m;
       cin >> m;
       int o;
       for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
       {
          cin >> o;
          arr[i].push_back(o);
       }
    }
    int r,s;
    for(int k=1;k<b;k++)
    {
      cin>>r>>s;
      cout <<a[r][s]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. For a useful answer explain why this is an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() 
{
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector<int>* a;
    a= new vector<int>[n];
    int p;
    int k;
    for (p = 0;p < n;p++) {
        cin >> k;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            int o;
            cin >>o;
            a[p].push_back(o);
        }
    }
    int r, s;
    for (p = 0;p < q;p++)
    {
        cin >> r >> s;
        cout << a[r][s]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi ,please explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is about handling vectors of the vector.

```
int main() {
  
    int n,q;
    cin>>n>>q;
    vector<vector<int> > a;//creating vectors of vector
    int k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >>k;
        vector <int> row; // creating vector

        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            int val;
            cin>> val;
            row.push_back(val);
        }
        a.push_back(row);
    }
    
    for (int l=0; l < q; l++)
    {
       int i,j;
       cin>>i>>j;
       // checking boundary conditions
       if ((i >= 0 && i < a.size() ) && (j >=0 && j < a[i].size()))
       {
          cout<<a[i][j]<<endl;
       }
      
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{   
    vector<vector<int>> MultiArry;
    vector<int> output;
    int n1,n2, q;
    int i,j;
    
    cin >> n1 >> q;
    MultiArry.resize(n1);
    output.resize(q);
    for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        cin >> n2; 
        MultiArry[i].resize(n2);
        for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
        {
            cin >> MultiArry[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    for(int ii=0;ii<q;ii++)
    {
        cin >> i >> j;
        output[ii] = MultiArry[i][j];
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        cout << output[i] << endl;
        
    return 0;
}
```