# What does while(cin) really mean?

Tags: c++, stream, boolean, cin, conversion-operator

I know while(cin) means while all previous operations on cin have succeeded, continue to loop. But what does that really mean?

Does it mean "after I have inputed all the values I want continue the loop" or "after completing the inputes that comes before continue the loop"  or what? I'm confused.

If there is no imput before while(cin) what then will happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between while(cin) and while(cin >> num)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483126/whats-the-difference-between-whilecin-and-whilecin-num)

Comment: It really means that `cin` is currently in a good state.  Inside the loop, still need to check for successful streaming into a variable, `if (!(cin >> num)) throw "Nope";` (or however one wants to handle failure).

Comment: Initially `cin` will be in good state, so it's `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The class `std::istream` inherits the class `std::basic_ios` that contains the conversion operator

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

that returns `!fail()`.

In the context of the while statement the object of the type `std::cin` is converted to an object of the type bool using this operator.

In fact this while loop is equivalent to

```
while ( not std::cin.fail() )
```

That is the loop will perform its iterations until some error or end of the stream will be encountered.

Comment: Could you expain better?

Comment: @Lekan What is unclear? Don't you understand this while loop while ( not std::cin.fail() )?

Comment: Yeah I totally dont

Comment: @Lekan The body of the loop is executed until some error condition of the input stream will occur.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it. I was just complicating things for myself.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple piece of code, you can get your code to run over and over (something like a infinite loop):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   while (cin) {
      cout << "HI";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but there are no former inputs. What if there are other inputs outside the while statement