# why does this for loop in C++ using getline() work

Tags: c++, for-loop

I compiled this nested for loop in C++. It works, however I don't understand why. Can you please explain the mechanics, and also any information on why the `push_back()` is allowed in addition to the increment.

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); text->push_back(line), ++ln) // why does this work? 
{
  // do something
  std::istringstream iss(line); 
  for (std::string word; iss>>word;) // why does this work? 
    // do something
};
```

`text` is a `shared_ptr<vector<string>>`.

Comment: it's a `for` loop, but there's no increment part

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19483126/14193797) to understand `iss>>word` part

Comment: @VladfromMoscow want to provide some reference books if this is so easy?

Comment: @TWhite Somewhere at SO there is a reference to recommended books on C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop

```
for (A; B; C)
{
    D;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    A;
    while (B)
    {
        D;
        C;
    }
}
```

and any of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` can be empty.
If those parts are syntactically correct in the while loop, they are also correct in the corresponding for loop.

So your nested loop is equivalent to

```
{

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line); 
        {
            std::string word; 
            while (iss>>word)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
        text->push_back(line), ++ln;
    }
}
```

Note that the `push_back` line uses the comma operator for sequencing because the semicolon is the delimiter in the for-loop header.

Answer (score 3):

Every part of a `for` loop [is optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for#Explanation).

If there is no iteration expression, it nothing is done between the body and testing the condition. In this case that's fine, as the condition does the work.

Any expression that contextually coverts to `bool` can go in the condition.

You can chain multiple expressions with [`,`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), it will evaluate them left to right and discard the values of all but the last.

Comment: This was a really good, succinct explanation. I ended up accepting @molbdlino answer as the examples he provided unrolled the for loop components into separable chunks. I did upvote this answer as well as it complements the accepted answer.